# $controller->referer() with local=true

Tags: php, cakephp

I have this simple code

```
debug($this->referer('foo', true));
debug($this->referer('foo', false));
```

I expect to obtain the same result when I come from a local address i.e.

```
'http://example.com/index.php/admin/groups'
'http://example.com/index.php/admin/groups'
```

Instead I obtain this:

```
'http://example.com/index.php/admin/users/foo'
'http://example.com/index.php/admin/groups'
```

as you can see when I set local to true cakePHP referer() return the default address even when the referer is in the local server

I'm using cakePHP 2.4

Comment: If you come from a local address how is it pointing to `example.com`? Do you mean localhost or another internal host? What exactly is it saying?

Comment: from the manual: 

    Parameter $local if set to true, restricts referring URLs to local server.

I believe that 'local' means 'from the same server' and not 'form localhost'. Am I wrong?

Comment: If you see the api it explains: `$local: Attempt to return a local address. Local addresses do not contain hostnames.`

And you can see what exactly it does in the [codebase](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-CakeRequest.html#414-440).

Comment: thanks so muche but I still don't get it. If I use `CakeRequest::referer()` I'll obtain 'http://example.com/index.php/admin/groups' but if I use `CakeRequest::referer(true)` why I get '/' instead of '/index.php/admin/groups'?

Answer (score 0):

Normally `index.php` shouldn't be shown in the URL unless you have apache's `mod_rewrite` and rules deactivated (or the equivalent of other http servers) and you enabled Cake's built in [pretty URL's](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#core-configuration-baseurl).

According to the code base `$this->referer()`, will return `/` in the following situations with `$local = true`:

1. `env('HTTP_REFERER')` is empty **AND** you haven't configured `App.fullBaseUrl` in `core.php`.
2. Your `env('HTTP_REFERER')` doesn't start with exactly `App.fullBaseUrl . $this->webroot` (i.e. `www.example.com/index.php`).

Also if `env('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST')` is set it replaces the references to `env('HTTP_REFERER')` above.

Judging from the two alternatives I would put my money on `App.fullBaseUrl` not being defined :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have `mod_rewrite` deactivated and I can't activate it. `Configure::read('App.fullBaseUrl')` returns the expected value but `App.fullBaseUrl . $this->webroot` returns  `www.example.com/app/webroot/` so I'm in the situation #2. What can I do?